# Applying conditional formatting row-wise

Tags: worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to create conditional formatting based on the following spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet]

My intention is that if `Space` is not empty and `Note` is, the cell will glow red with anger. I'm using the following formula for the conditional formatting: `=and(if(isblank(D2),"FALSE","TRUE"),if(isblank(E2),"TRUE","FALSE"))`

Looks great, but that only works for cell `E2`. How can I drag the conditional formatting down through the rest of the (3000) cells? When I drag the conditioning down now, every cell is conditional on `D2` and `E2`, rather than, for example, cell `E3` being conditional on `D3` and `E3`.

Thanks!

Comment: I actually want the opposite of absolute reference--I want cell `E3` to be based on `D3` and `E3`, cell `E4` to be based on `D4` and `E4`, etc.

Comment: It doesn't affect the formatting. Maybe it's a limitation of Google Sheets (that's what I'm using)? But writing the formatting formula for `E2` then pulling on the fill handle is still filling each cell with `=and(if(isblank(D2),"FALSE","TRUE"),if(isblank(E2),"TRUE","FALSE")`, only now it's `isblank($D2)` and `isblank($E2)`.

Comment: What I suggested is for Excel, I removed the tag, since it doesn't apply

Comment: Try to apply the same condition to an entire range at once